# Firebase database пробема с заданием прав пользователей

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-database

Необходимо по заданию разделить права проверенных администратором пользователем с помощью флага verified.

[image: в таком виде находятся в бд]

Однако не получается никакими способами задать права как бы не пытался

".write":

```
root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('roles').child('verified').val() === true
```

не работает, ошибка:

> Listener at /users/JKeMMWEvpZfW8I77j02lEJ3ZocJ2 failed: permission_denied

Подскажите, как сделать.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Покажи правила бд. Ошибка в них.

Comment: @ValeraKvip 
{
  "rules": {
    "orders": {
      ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('roles').child('verified').val() === 'true'",
      ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('roles').child('verified').val() === 'true'"
    }
  }
}